# Loop over data values in neo4j

Tags: loops, neo4j, cypher

I have a movies.csv file, which has a feature vector per line (E.g - id|Name|0|1|1|0|0|0|1  has 2 features for name and id, 7 features for genre classification)

I want a node m from class Movies to have a relationship [:HAS_GENRE] with nodes g from class Genres. For that, I need to loop over all the '|' separated features and only make a relationship if the value is 1.

IN essence, I want to have -

```
x = a //where a is the index of the first genre feature

while (x < lim) //lim is the last index of the feature vector
{
if line[x] is 1:
    (m{id:toInt(line[0]})-[:HAS_GENRE]->(g{id=line[x]})

}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I know the match and create constructs, just no idea about the loop part.

Comment: You have a .csv file with a single column that's pipe delimited?

Comment: all columns are pipe-delimited

Comment: How do you identify the feature vector?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH ["Genre1","Genre2",...] as genres
LOAD CSV FROM "file:movies.pdv" using fieldterminator "|" AS row
MERGE (m:Movie {id:row[0]}) ON CREATE SET m.title = row[1]
FOREACH (idx in filter(range(0,size(genres)-1) WHERE row[2+idx]="1") )  |
   MERGE (g:Genre {name:genres[idx]})
   CREATE (m)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(g)
)
```

- it loads each row of the file of as a collection
- the first two elements are used to create a movie
- then filter the potential indexes `range(0,size(genres)-1)` by the existence of a "1" in the input row,
- the resulting list of indexes is then used to lookup the genre-name or id
- and connect the movie with the genre

Comment: It doesn't work when I put "match (g:Genres) return g" inside the [ ] for genres. I want the list to be dynamically retrieved, how can I do that? I already have a list of (:Genres) nodes.